# WLAN and bluetooth not working in ubuntu 22.04 on dual booting

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, 22.04, mediatek, windows-11

I have an *Asus Vivobook(2023)* Laptop with **Windows 11** installed.
When I dual booted it with **Ubuntu 22.04LTS**, the Wi-Fi option did not appear. Simultaneously, the bluetooth is also not working.
Following are the relevant details.

- Bitlocker removed.
- Secure Boot is disabled.
- Fast Boot is disabled.

```
$ uname -rms
Linux 6.2.0-36-generic x86_64
```

```
$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH SMBus Controller
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH LPC Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 5520
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5411 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Micron Technology Inc Device 2100
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c5)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 29dd
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0300000-e03fffff memory:fcf00000-fcf07fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: wlx1cbfce6dedb5
       serial: 1c:bf:ce:6d:ed:b5
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=6.2.0-36-generic firmware=N/A ip=***.***.***.*** link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
$ls /etc/modprobe.d/
alsa-base.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf
blacklist-modem.conf
blacklist-rare-network.conf
iwlwifi.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf
blacklist-oss.conf
intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
```

It seems to be a Mediatek adapter. I have tried installing the Mediatek driver from Asus's webpage in windows and it works perfectly in windows, but **no success** in Ubuntu.
One thing I have **not** tried is **changing the kernel version**, because elsewhere it suggests to upgrade kernel to latest one. And I am already running the latest kernel version 6.2.
There is no driver suggestion shown in **Software Update Center** in additional drivers section.
I have tried using Mediatek driver by referencing [How to install Mediatek MT7630E wireless LAN driver in Linux Mint/Ubuntu](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796).

Comment: Found out that the adapter is `Mediatek MT7902` in windows. A number of threads shows there is no support yet in linux.